# Remove first n character from bunch of file names with cut

Tags: bash, cut

I am using

`ls | cut -c 5-`

This does return a list of the file names in the format i want them, but doesn't actually perform the action. Please advise.

Comment: If you are on Mac or Linux, just open the terminal, CD to the folder with your files, and do `for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:5}"; done`. This will 'cut' the first five chars from all the files in that folder.

Comment: @Kebman that works perfectly.
However if I try without CDing and point the directory through a variable, it doesn't work. The code:
`search_dir=/Users/veller/Desktop/folder; for entry in "$search_dir"/*; do mv "$entry" "${entry:5}"; done`
It gives me the following error: No such file or directory

Comment: use `for f in *.*` in Kebman comment to avoid subfolders.

Answer (score 79):

```
rename -n 's/.{5}(.*)/$1/' *
```

The `-n` is for simulating; remove it to get the actual result.

Comment: For macOS, you can install `brew` https://brew.sh/ and then `brew install rename` to use this

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I ran it on my folder, but nothing changed.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was using the `linux-util` version of `rename` instead of the perl script. For any arch users, you have to install the official `perl-rename` package.

Answer (score 33):

you can use the following command when you are in the folder where you want to make the renaming:

```
rename -n -v  's/^(.{5})//' *
```

`-n` is for no action and `-v` to show what will be the changes. if you are satisfied with the results you can remove both of them

```
rename 's/^(.{5})//' *
```

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should work:

```
for x in *; do
    echo mv $x `echo $x | cut -c 5-`
done
```

Note that this could be destructive, so run it this way first, and then remove the leading `echo` once you're confident that it does what you want.

Comment: With the first `echo` removed and as written, wouldn't this only works without errors if the directory only contains files without spaces in the name and are at least 6 characters long?  While double-quoting `$x` and using `$(..)` instead of legacy use of back-ticks would take of filename with spaces errors however that alone would not take care of all errors that could be thrown, e.g. if a filename is only 5 characters long or there are directories.

Comment: echo mv $x ${x:5}

Comment: Nice and straightforward. You can use this to verify the new filename before adding the mv command to the one-liner: `for fn in *; do newfn=$(echo $fn | cut -c 19-); echo will move $fn to $newfn; done`

Answer (score 4):

Kebman's little code is nice for if you want to cut off the leading dot of hidden files and folders in the current dir, before 7zipping or zipping.

I put this in a bash script, but this is wat I mean:

```
for f in .*; do mv -v "$f" "${f:1}"; done # cut off the leading point of hidden files and dirs

7z a -pPASSWORD -mx=0 -mhe -t7z ${DESTINATION}.7z ${SOURCE} -x!7z_Compress_not_this_script_itself_*.sh # compress all files and dirs of current dir to one 7z-file, excluding the script itself.
```

zip and 7z can have trouble with hidden files at top level in the current dir.
Hidden files in the subdirs are accepted.

```
mydir/myfile = ok
mydir/.myfile = ok
.mydir/myfile = nok
.mydir/.myfile = nok
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error message saying,

> rename is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

This might work for you,

```
get-childitem * | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(5) }
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution for Windows. Works well with PowerShell.